# Нужна ли запятая в таком предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте! Нужна ли запятая после "узнайте" в предложении типа "Узнайте как определить свой тип"? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Узнайте, как определить свой тип.

СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, союзное слово КАК, запятая ставится.

Comment: Вера, не поняла, при чём здесь косвенная речь, здесь нет передачи чьей-то речи от 3 лица, просто придаточное. А вопросительный знак у автора вопроса в вопросительном предложении: Нужна ли запятая после "узнайте" в предложении ...? Всё верно.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю нужна запятая. Узнайте, как определить свой тип.

Comment: Желательно писать более обоснованные ответы.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к пожеланию.